# When creating the object, the program hangs without errors in ‘Output'

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Creation of the first object goes without problems, it is saved on Firebase and uploaded to the application. When creating the second object, the program hangs without errors in ‘Output'

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices
import AlertKit
import Firebase

struct Themes: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var firebaseController = FirebaseController()
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = AlertViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var changer: ChangeViewManager
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @StateObject private var alertManager = CustomAlertManager()
    @StateObject private var themeController = ThemeController()
    @EnvironmentObject var store: IAPStore
    @State private var themeName: String = ""
    @State private var isSubscribed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                GeometryReader { frame in
                    VStack {
                        List {
                            if firebaseController.userThemes != [] {
                                ForEach(firebaseController.userUniqueSections, id: \.self) { section in
                                    Section(header: Text(section)) {
                                        ForEach(self.firebaseController.userThemesCollatedBySections[section]!.filter({ (theme) -> Bool in
                                            themeName = theme.name
                                            return themeName.hasPrefix(themeController.searchText) || themeController.searchText == ""
                                        }), id: \.self)  { theme in
                                            NavigationLink(
                                                destination: Words(newWord: NewWordModel(), theme: theme).environmentObject(self.firebaseController),
                                                label: {
                                                    ThemeRow(theme: theme, firebaseController: firebaseController, isSubscribed: $isSubscribed)
                                                })
                                        }
                                        .onDelete(perform: delete)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ForEach(firebaseController.uniqueSections, id: \.self) { section in
                                Section(header: Text(section)) {
                                    ForEach(self.firebaseController.themesCollatedBySections[section]!.filter({ (theme: Theme) -> Bool in
                                        return theme.name.hasPrefix(themeController.searchText) || themeController.searchText == ""
                                    }), id: \.self) { theme in
                                        if  theme.fixed == false || isSubscribed == true {
                                            NavigationLink(
                                                destination: Words(newWord: NewWordModel(), theme: theme)
                                                    .environmentObject(self.firebaseController),
                                                label: {
                                                    ThemeRow(theme: theme, firebaseController: firebaseController, isSubscribed: $isSubscribed)
                                                })
                                        } else {
                                            NavigationLink(
                                                destination: PayWall(),
                                                label: {
                                                    ThemeRow(theme: theme, firebaseController: firebaseController, isSubscribed: $isSubscribed)
                                                })
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            UnlockWords(isSubscribed: $isSubscribed)
                        }
                        .task {
                            isSubscribed = await store.isPurchased(store.defaults.string(forKey: "product") ?? "" )
                        }
                    }
                }
                .searchable(text: $themeController.searchText)
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                .navigationTitle("Themes")
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                        Button(action: {
                    changer.changerView = .loginView
                    firebaseController.signOut()
                }, label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "lock.open.fill")
                            .opacity(firebaseController.isUserUID(have: 0.0, no: 1.0))
                        Text("Sign in")
                            .opacity(firebaseController.isUserUID(have: 0.0, no: 1.0))
                    }
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                })
                                        .disabled(firebaseController.isUserUID(have: true, no: false))
                                    ,trailing:
                                        Button(action: {
                    alertManager.show()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(azure)
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .opacity(firebaseController.isUserUID(have: 1.0, no: 0.0))
                })
                                        .disabled(firebaseController.isUserUID(have: false, no: true))
                )
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Add new Theme")
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                    Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "play.fill")
            })
            .customAlert(manager: alertManager, content: {
                VStack {
                    Text("Add new theme")
                        .bold24()
                        .padding(.top, 30)
                        .padding(.bottom, 30)
                    TextField("Irregular verbs", text: $themeController.textEntered).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                }
            }, buttons: [
                .cancel(content: {
                    Text("Cancel")
                }),
                .regular(content: {
                    Text("Add").bold()
                }, action: {
                    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {return}
                    let user = Users(user: currentUser)
                    firebaseController.updateTheme(user: user, themeName: themeController.textEntered) { result in
                        switch result {
                        case .success():
                            firebaseController.getUserTheme()
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }
                    print("Add theme: \(themeController.textEntered)")
                })
            ])
            .onAppear {
                Task {
                   await store.requestProducts()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        firebaseController.userThemes.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        firebaseController.deleteTheme(themeName: themeName)
        firebaseController.getUserTheme()
    }
}
```

```
struct ThemeRow: View {
    
    @State var theme: Theme
    @State private var progress = 0.0
    @EnvironmentObject var store: IAPStore
    @ObservedObject var firebaseController: FirebaseController
    @EnvironmentObject var changer: ChangeViewManager
    @Binding var isSubscribed: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ThemeImage(theme: $theme)
                ThemeName(theme: $theme)
                  Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .foregroundColor(darkLimeGreen)
                    .font(.system(size: 18,
                                  weight: .bold))
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "lock.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(charcoalGreyTwo)
                    .font(.system(size: theme.fixed == true && isSubscribed == false ? 24 : 0, weight: .bold))
                    .opacity(theme.sections == "personal themes" ? 0 : 1)
            }
            .padding(.top, 10)
            .padding(.bottom,10)
            HStack {
                ThemeProgress(progress: $progress)
                ThemeProgressLabel(theme: $theme)
            }
        }
        .padding(.bottom,10)
        .task {
            isSubscribed = await store.isPurchased(store.defaults.string(forKey: "product") ?? "" )
        }
    }
}
```

**A method for creating a new object:**

```
func getUserTheme() {
        guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {return}
        let user = Users(user: currentUser)
        
        let themeUser = userDB.child(user.uid).child("userInfo").child("themes")
        themeUser.observe(.childAdded, with: { [weak self] snapshot in
            
            if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                if
                    let name         = data["name"]         as? String,
                    let fixed        = data["fixed"]        as? Bool,
                    let oldCount     = data["oldCount"]     as? Int,
                    let learnCount   = data["learnCount"]   as? Int,
                    let date         = data["date"]         as? String,
                    let subscription = data["subscription"] as? String,
                    let sections     = data["sections"]     as? String,
                    let imageTheme   = data["imageTheme"]   as? String {
                    
                    let theme = Theme(name: name,
                                      fixed: fixed,
                                      oldCount: oldCount,
                                      learnCount: learnCount,
                                      date: date,
                                      subscription: subscription,
                                      sections: sections,
                                      imageTheme: imageTheme)
                    self?.userThemes.append(theme)
                    self?.objectWillChange.send(self!)
                }
            }
        })
```

Checked on 15.2 on simulator and on iPhone 7 15.2.1

The problem, it seems to me, is with this SF: systemName: "lock.fill"

How can I get rid of this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: First thing to do: pare this down to a [mre]. My suspicion is it just has to be a `View` with `var body : { Image(systemName: "lock.fill") }`. If so, you can get rid of the other superfluous code in the question, as it doesn't relate to the issue. Second thing to do: make sure to include what version of iOS/macOS this is running on and if it's a device or simulator.

Comment: "...the program hangs without errors in ‘Output'...", there is so much going on that I could not find `Output`. What is the error and where does it happen?

Comment: The program just hangs, because the second object is not processed for display on the screen.    **self?.userThemes.append(theme)**   But it is saved in Firebase, that is, the problem is in the display when processing an array of objects, as I understand it.